# Tab Bar Controller badge not being set?

Tags: ios, badge, tabbarcontroller

I am trying to set a tab bar item's badge from the tab bar controllers class and its not working.

First, I create a `TabBarController` by dragging it out into the storyboard.

[image]

Then, I create three `ViewControllers` and connect them to the `TabBarController`.

[image]

Then I create four classes, the first one is a `TabBarController` class and the rest are `ViewControllerClasses`.

[image]

Then, I link up the classes to the storyboard elements, example:
[image]

Then, In the `TabBarViewController` class, I add in this code into the `ViewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1] 

setBadgeValue:@"1"];
}
```

[image]

Now when I run the app, I would expect the 2nd tab bar item to have a badge with a value of `@"1"`, however, none of the tab bars show any badge?!

[image]

My issue is that I want the badge updated of one of the tab bar items, however its not working. **Also, It is important I can set the value of the tab bar badge to a tab bar item of a view controller that *isn't loaded*, that part is crucial for my app to work.**

So why isn't this working and how can I make it work?

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is that create three navigationControllers and connect them to the TabBarController, and the three navigationControllers are as rootVIewController of your navigationController.

Comment: @Allen thanks but how will that solve this problem?

Comment: In your one of  three viewControllers, write `[[self navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"YourBadgeValue";`. Or as your code, but place it into viewController(not tabBarViewController).

Comment: @Allen, as I said in my post, I want to set the badge value from a **different class**. That is not what I need to achieve...

Comment: Whatever a different class, you get the tabBarController first, and then you can get all rootViewControllers through `UITabBarController`'s `viewControllers` property.

Comment: @Allen Thanks for help! You are save my time and nerves! Really i have big brainstorm why badge didn't appeared..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1]
```

because self is a `UITabBarViewController`, so you don't need to get tabBarController again. Use the code below to get `UITabBarItem`

```
[[[self tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1]
```